# Using a different image in a script based on the user's choice from a <select>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a script that shows an animation following the mouse cursor.  I initialize it by running this code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
function JSFX_StartEffects()
{
JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/ant_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/ant_tail.gif'>"
);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

This is one of many functions that run onload, so I'm using jQuery's DOM ready handler:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ JSFX_StartEffects() });
</SCRIPT>
```

This is working fine, but I'd like to add the option for the user to chose a different pair of images for the animation. I have four different pairs of options, so I added a `<select>` to my document:

```
<div>
<div class="bebete">
<div>Choisis ta Bebete ! :))))</div>
<br>
<div>
<select id="select1">
<option selected>alien_ant</option> 
<option>alien_arachnid</option> 
<option>cute_worm</option> 
<option>alien_caterpillar</option> 
</select>
</div>
<div>
<br><br>      
<img id="preview1" alt="image" src="http://tip-top-torrents.net/JSFX/alien_ant.jpg"
width="180" h   eight="180">
<h3 id="random1"></h3>
</div>
<br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = [];
var select1 = window.document.getElementById("select1");
var preview1 = window.document.getElementById("preview1");
var random1 = window.document.getElementById("random1");
var selectLength = select1.length;
images[0] = "http://tip-top-torrents.net/JSFX/alien_ant.jpg";
images[1] = "http://tip-top-torrents.net/JSFX/alien_arachnid.jpg";
images[2] = "http://tip-top-torrents.net/JSFX/cute_worm.jpg";
images[3] = "http://tip-top-torrents.net/JSFX/alien_caterpillar.jpg";

function edit_image1() {
var index = select1.selectedIndex;
if (index !== 0) {
preview1.src = images[index];
random1.style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {        
preview1.src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectLength)];
random1.style.visibility = "visible";
}
return true;
}
select1.onchange = edit_image1;
</script>

</div>
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to apply the user's choice when initializing the animation.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
function JSFX_StartEffects()
{

var Img.src = document.getElementById('preview1.src');
```

Here I need to use a condition. If the user has chosen `alien_ant`, then it must be initialized with this pair of images:

```
JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/ant_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/ant_tail.gif'>");
```

If not, I need to compare the user's choice to the other options and apply the appropriate image pair.

```
JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/worm_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/worm_tail.gif'>");
JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/spider_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/spider_tail.gif'>");
JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/alien_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/alien_tail.gif'>");
```

```
}
</SCRIPT>
```

What is the best way to do this?

You can find the original script I'm using near the end of [this page](http://www.javascript-fx.com/mouse_trail/index.html), under "MouseSquidie".

Comment: Read the FAQ and try reposting as this one will certainly be closed. Questions are expected to be well thought out, grammatically correct and not contain dozens of random arfs and smiley faces. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I did... though really I don't see quite why I bothered.

Comment: @cocodjidji: that is not the way to design for the Internet. It never was. It was a horrible fashion of many years ago. That is *the worst site I have seen for many years.*

Comment: If there must be a comment on your writing style (pre-edit, anyway), to what mrtsherman has said I'll add: typing incoherently and drunkenly on sites like this where professionals frequently visit is not going to reflect well on you, particularly with your employers. Even if you're unemployed today, you're much better off sorting this out now if you want to be taken seriously by *anybody*.

Comment: if a real java coder read my question, he will resolve it in seconds, right ? so iam not a player, i wait after a real coder .... not writing lessons, and wooo i am not english, as you should had understood, so i write as i can, lol :))))

Comment: This site is for *professionals* to help each others. We have many non-English users, that's fine. You're not being judged for that, but because you needlessly filled your posts with smilies, repeated punctuation and meaningless words. Your post, as it was written, was practically incomprehensible and was closed. If we allowed posts like that on the site, it will turn away the users who can actually help people; who would want to put so much effort into understanding your question? Your post was only re-opened because certain users decided to edit it and improve it, and it's still borderline.

Comment: haaa ok ok, so many thanks for correcting my post, formatting it, sorry about the smilies, i come from some underground places, trackers, i mainly code new trackers in fact, amzing ones, THIS site, tip top torrents is just a top list i did for fun and trying to make more pleasant .... to have fun. if you wanna see some of my others sites, more "professionals", i will show you ... just have a lookt at this one :  hipxsite.net .... but i am not a professional at all. i hope the way you corrected it, my post will stay, see u and thanks again Jeremy !!!

Comment: so ... gonna look at one of my style changer, maybe i could find the solution by my self, after all, as ... usual , hihihiiiiii BUT if someone get some idea, its ok, lol ...  go see my tracker, you will see what a noob can do ... ha ha :)   hipxsite.net

Comment: We're here to help, and if you want us to help you, which we're doing _for free_, you could at least be assed to put some time into what you type.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your images are named systematically you could do something like this:

Set the value of your options to the variable part of the file name:

```
<option value="ant" selected="selected">Ant</option> 
<option value="arachnid">Arachnid</option> 
<option value="worm">Worm</option> 
<option value="caterpillar">Caterpillar</option>
```

then replace all the js you got there and call the trailing mouse function with the value from that select element like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        JSFX.MakeMouseSquidie (15,"<img src='JSFX/" + $(this).val() + "_head.gif'>" ,"<img src='JSFX/" + $(this).val() + "_tail.gif'>");
    });
});
```

Comment: *I hope this web page you're putting together is for an 8yr old btw. No one seriously puts trailing mouse stuff on real websites.